# Separate php.ini file for each Apache virtual host?

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini, virtualhost

Is it possible to have a separate php.ini file that overrides the default php.ini file for each virtual host? I'm running Apache/2.2.14, PHP 5.3.2-1.

For example, I have several vhosts pointing to domains in my `/var/www/` directory:

```
/var/www/website1.com  
/var/www/website2.com
```

What I'd like is to be able to place a custom php.ini file in each directory that would override the default values only for that vhost, but keep the original defaults if the value isn't specified:

```
/var/www/website1.com/htdocs/
/var/www/website1.com/php.ini
```

**Edit**
For those interested, I found more info on the topic at [How do I set up per-site php.ini files on a LAMP server using NameVirtualHosts?](https://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using mod_php, you can override the values you wish in httpd.conf. There are these module directives:

```
php_value - PHP Value Modifier
php_flag - PHP Flag Modifier
php_admin_value - PHP Value Modifier (Admin)
php_admin_flag - PHP Flag Modifier (Admin)
```

If not, your best shot is PHP FPM (google it).

Comment: Yeah, I could also use an .htaccess in each vhost root to change the values as well, and from what I've read this is a good way to do it. 

But I know I've seen some shared-hosting webhosts that allow you to override their php.ini with their own, so there has to be another way to do it right?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using cgi (or fastcgi, or fpm, which is fastcgi too), you can use the [`.user.ini` files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php).

Simply place a `.user.ini` file in your webroot directory with your php options, as follows:

```
memory_limit=256M
upload_max_filesize=200M
post_max_size=200M
```

And php will extend the main php.ini file with that options.

Answer (score -2):

Add the PHPINIDir within the VirtualHost tag and point it to the directory your php.ini file that vhost will be using.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
[....]
PHPINIDir /var/www/web1
[....]
</VirtualHost>
```

grabbed from http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

Edit 14/04/2010 12:30pm EST:
** Nevermind, this changed the "Loaded Configuration File" for all vhosts.  **

Comment: PHPINIDir loads that php.ini for ALL virtual hosts, and not only the one you put it in. I got caught assuming the same :(