# Customized user php.ini

Tags: php, apache-2.2

On each virtualhost, I have a custom php.ini:

```
PHPINIDir /var/www/site1/php.ini
```

What I currently do is copy the original `/etc/php.ini` to `/var/www/site1/php.ini` then do the modifications. But it's a headache, how can I just enter only the values which I want to change so the content of `/var/www/site1/php.ini` for example will just override the default php.ini?

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

Comment: It seems duplicate Q, which is also answered here: http://serverfault.com/questions/144021/separate-php-ini-file-for-each-apache-virtual-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `php_value` to override specific values, e.g. `php_value memory_limit 256M`.

Comment: I would be putting that in my virtualhost file?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in the vhost or even inside a `.htaccess`