# Custom PHPINIDir setting in VirtualHost affecting other VirtualHosts

Tags: apache-2.2, php, freebsd

One of the clients requested a personal php.ini configuration for his website, so I have set his VirtualHost as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/alex/www.domain.tld"
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    AssignUserID alex alex
    PHPINIDir /home/alex/php.ini
</VirtualHost>
```

The client created php.ini file under /home/alex/ which contains only this setting:

`session.save_path = "/home/alex/.php_sessions/"`

After this was done, he started to complain that he sees all the other session files generated by other clients' websites.

After doing some basic troubleshooting, I realized that his php.ini settings are affecting all websites specified in the httpd-vhosts.conf.

Question is why? Since `PHPINIDir` is only specified inside one specific `VirtualHost`?

Comment: You aren't supposed to include the actual filename, just the path /home/alex I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Individual virtualhosts cannot have their own `PHPINIDir` because the `php.ini` file is read when apache+mod_php starts up, before it even begins handling requests.  For whatever reason, instead of giving a warning with this usage this directive will set the global INI directory and continue on its merry way.

Instead, you must use the `php_value`, `php_flag`, `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag` Apache directives to override the specific settings you want for this virtual host.  (See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/144022/56830))  In this case, you would do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/alex/www.domain.tld"
    ServerName www.domain.tld
    AssignUserID alex alex
    php_value session.save_path "/home/alex/.php_sessions/"
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case, it would load the default `php.ini` file, then change `session.save_path` to the given directory, just for this virtualhost.

Comment: I cannot let users edit httpd-vhosts.conf, in this case i need to program some front-end interface, which is not an easy option...

Comment: @Radio The `php_value` and `php_flag` settings can be used in `.htaccess` if `AllowOverride Options` is set.