# Apache VirtualHosts define php.ini but extend main php.ini

Tags: apache-2.2, php.ini

I have a main *php.ini* file and am wondering if it is possible to specify a custom *php.ini* for a virtualhost, but this *php.ini* would extend the main *php.ini* file, so that only the specified settings are overridden and everything else is taken the main *php.ini*. For example:

I have my main php.ini file in */etc/php5/php.ini*, containing all the defaults. Let's say this has everything as default so e.g.

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
```

Then I have my virtualhost located at */home/user/php.ini* and this contains the following:

```
allow_url_fopen = Off
```

This php would run with first the php.ini in */etc/php5/php.ini* then the settings that are in */home/user/php.ini* resulting in a configuration where both `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` are set to Off.

Edit:
Also, if */home/user/php.ini* does not exist, it would default back to */etc/php5/php.ini*

Comment: See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/34078/how-do-i-set-up-per-site-php-ini-files-on-a-lamp-server-using-namevirtualhosts

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend this alternative approach, which works quite well for multiple different virtualhost sites:

Override specific php.ini files via virtualhost variables.  For example, my current web server has these php.ini overloading values:

```
php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 180000
# allow sessions to last approximately two days
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 200000
php_value session.cache_expire 200000
# allow session cookie to last a little longer than two days.
# Change expose_php value in php.ini to off.
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

In this way you can bundle your php.ini config values with your apache config for specific sites, and have custom php.ini values per virtualhost.